# how do i pipe values of mulitple records into one in SQL?

Tags: pipe, sql-server-2014

I would like to display the following data:

```
PID   SQ  SQ1  DS
123   12  1    ABC
321   13  1    BBC
321   13  2    CNN
322   15  1    DFG
321   13  3    AMG
```

Like this:

```
PID  DS_output
123  ABC
321  BBC|CNN|AMG
322  DFG
```

Can someone suggest or post an example of a query I can use to retrieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use STUFF function combine by FOR XML PATH

```
CREATE TABLE #t (PID INT, SQ INT, SQ1 INT, DS VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #t
VALUES (123, 12, 1, 'ABC')
    , (321, 13, 1, 'BBC')
    , (321, 13, 2, 'CNN')
    , (322, 15, 1, 'DFG')
    , (321, 13, 3, 'AMG')

SELECT DISTINCT PID, stuff((
            SELECT '|' + it.DS
            FROM #t it
            WHERE PID = ot.PID
            ORDER BY it.PID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
FROM #t ot
```